# After localization i get clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2

I just translated my entire app into another language by adding localization to some of my nib and .m files and after I got done and I tried to run the app I get the following error.

> Ld
>   "/Users/tenghamn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scheduleTable-djaxkjmejcrgsybqqoinnhkerlut/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MDH Schedule.app/MDH Schedule" normal i386 cd
>
> "/Users/tenghamn/Dropbox/xcode Projects/scheduleTable" setenv
>   MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6 setenv PATH
>   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk
>
> -L/Users/tenghamn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scheduleTable-djaxkjmejcrgsybqqoinnhkerlut/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>
> -F/Users/tenghamn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scheduleTable-djaxkjmejcrgsybqqoinnhkerlut/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>
> -filelist "/Users/tenghamn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scheduleTable-djaxkjmejcrgsybqqoinnhkerlut/Build/Intermediates/scheduleTable.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/scheduleTable.build/Objects-normal/i386/MDH
>
> Schedule.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker
>
> -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreData
>   -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o
>
> "/Users/tenghamn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scheduleTable-djaxkjmejcrgsybqqoinnhkerlut/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MDH Schedule.app/MDH Schedule"
>
> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in
>   /Users/tenghamn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scheduleTable-djaxkjmejcrgsybqqoinnhkerlut/Build/Intermediates/scheduleTable.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/scheduleTable.build/Objects-normal/i386/MainViewController-96B8D44EBB24B056.o
>
> and
>
> /Users/tenghamn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scheduleTable-djaxkjmejcrgsybqqoinnhkerlut/Build/Intermediates/scheduleTable.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/scheduleTable.build/Objects-normal/i386/MainViewController-4CC6B4B54C957278.o
>
> for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have searched for solutions to this error but nothing seems to solve my issue or be directly related. Any ideas on what I can do to solve it?

Comment: Its look like you have a duplicate MainViewController . . . How you did your localization ? Is it by adding localization files? What you tried so far?

Comment: I have checked for duplicates and don't see any. I have tried doing a clean and then building again but the error persists. To add the localization I clicked on MainViewController.m and in the file inspector under Localization i clicked the plus sign, the first time it gave me english, and then the second time I created Swedish. Then I selected the newly created MainViewController.m (Swedish) and made the necessary changes. I checked my project folder and there is one MainViewController.m in en.lproj and one MainViewController.m in sv.lproj. I did the same for other .m files and nib files.

Comment: If i remove the MainViewController.m (Swedish) file it works, is there a way I can make the swedish verison use a different name

Answer (score 0):

I did the translation directly in the files. You need to utilize NSLocalizedstring and a strings file to make this work otherwise xcode will try to use two .m files with the same name.